# A diophantine equation of degree 3

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Find the integer solutions of $y^2+6=x^3$. I guess it does not have integer solutions but I cannot prove it. By $\pmod 8$, I can know that $y$ is odd and $x\equiv7 \pmod 8$. Then what else can I do?

Comment: Just guess and checked $x=1$ to $x=100$ and got no integer solution for $y$, so $x > 100$.

Comment: Also, by $\pmod 9$, I'm getting $y \equiv 2 \pmod 9$ or $y \equiv 7 \pmod 9$, so $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Combining this with your conclusion, we get $x \equiv 7 \pmod{24}$.

Comment: Just guess and checked from $x=7$ to $x=24*70+7=1687$ and got no integer solution for $y$, so $x > 1687$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A081121 There are no integer solutions for $y^2 = x^3 - 6$. (Keyword: Mordell curve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) talks a lot about Mordell's equations. I haven't read through all of it, but on Page 2, Theorem 2.3, there is a proof of how $y^2=x^3-6$ has no integral solutions. Here's an outline of the proof:

1. Prove $y$ is odd and $x \equiv 7 \pmod 8$.
2. Get $y^2-2=x^3-8=(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)$. Note that the latter factor is always positive and is $\equiv 3 \pmod 8$.
3. Therefore, $x^2+2x+4$ must have a prime factor that is $\equiv \pm3 \pmod 8$ because otherwise, all of its prime factors are $\equiv \pm1 \pmod 8$, making it $\equiv \pm1 \pmod 8$.
4. Let the prime be $p \equiv \pm3 \pmod 8$. (Note that $p$ is an odd prime.) Thus, $p$ divides $y^2-2$, so $y^2 \equiv 2 \pmod p$.
5. Thus, $2$ is congruent to a square $\pmod p$ where $p$ is an odd prime. Using quadratic residues, we know $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod 8$, so we have a contradiction with the fact that $p \equiv \pm3 \pmod 8$.